# Error "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I am trying to deploy Shiny App through Docker using windows 10 machine(8GB RAM).

Here is the Dockerfile :

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker
  FROM rocker/shiny:3.6.3

# system libraries of general use
  RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
  libxml2-dev \
  libcairo2-dev \
  libsqlite3-dev \
  libmariadbd-dev \
  libmariadbclient-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libssh2-1-dev \
  unixodbc-dev \
  && install2.r --error \
  --deps TRUE \
  tidyverse \
  dplyr \
  devtools \
  formatR \
  remotes \
  selectr \
  caTools \
  BiocManager \
  && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages

  # copy necessary files
  ## app folder
  COPY /shinyapp/shinyapp.Rproj /srv/shiny-server/
  COPY /shinyapp/ui.R /srv/shiny-server/
  COPY /shinyapp/server.R /srv/shiny-server/
  COPY /shinyapp/global.R /srv/shiny-server/
  # install renv & restore packages
  RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("shiny", repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')'
  RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("shinydashboard", repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')'
  RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("glue", repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')'

  # expose port
  EXPOSE 3838

  RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server

  # run app on container start
  CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

The Folder Structure is as follows :

1. Dockerfile
2. shinyapp ---> global.R ,
   ui.R,
   server.R

I tried troubleshooting and checked the name of the files. Everything is correct.
But still getting the error

[image]

Any help will be great !!

Comment: what's the docker configuration filename?

Comment: The name of file is "Dockerfile"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps

- /Users/myUserName/.docker
- ls -a
- rm -rf .token_seed

if it doesn't resolve the issue

remove '.token_seed.lock' file as well